# Fill UITableView with dictionary from JSON Request iOS

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

The problem I have now is that I have arrays on this code.

Need to replace UItableView with the URL Request JSON respond Object and replace the Dictionary Values.

There is a method to clean the information and reload the table to refresh the new data or something that could become handy to achieve this?

```
#import "RecipeTableViewController.h"
#import "RecipeTableCell.h"
#import "RecipeDetailViewController.h"
#import "Recipe.h"

@interface RecipeTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecipeTableViewController
{
    NSArray *recipes;
    NSArray *searchResults;

    NSMutableArray *myObject;
    // A Dictionary Object
    NSDictionary *dictionary;

    NSString *name;
    NSString *subject;
    NSString *avatar;
    NSString *rate;
    NSString *bio;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    name = @"name";
    subject = @"subject";
    avatar = @"avatar";
    rate = @"rate";
    bio = @"bio";

    myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://latamig.com/data.json"]];

    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];


    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects)
    {
        NSString *name_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *subject_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"subjects"];
        NSString *avatar_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"avatar_s"];
        NSString *rate_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"user_rate"];
        NSString *bio_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"bio"];

        NSLog(@"Name: %@", name_data);
        NSLog(@"Subject: %@",subject_data);
        NSLog(@"Avatar: %@", avatar_data);
        NSLog(@"Rate: %@",rate_data);
        NSLog(@"Bio: %@",bio_data);

        dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      name_data,name,
                      subject_data,subject,
                      avatar_data,avatar,
                      rate_data,rate,
                      bio_data, bio, nil];

        [myObject addObject:dictionary];
    }



    // API CALL MAKE END

    /* Initialize the recipes array
    Recipe *recipe1 = [Recipe new];
    recipe1.name = @"Andruw";
    recipe1.prepTime = @"$255/h";
    recipe1.bio = @"I'm a Web developer working for 3 years as a Programmer on Facebook";
    recipe1.image = @"avatar1.jpg";


    recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipe1, nil];

     */



}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [recipes count];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 71;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
    RecipeTableCell *cell = (RecipeTableCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[RecipeTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Display recipe in the table cell
    Recipe *recipe = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        recipe = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = recipe.name;
    cell.bioLabel.text = recipe.bio;
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:recipe.image];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width /2;
    cell.prepTimeLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cell.prepTimeLabel.text = recipe.prepTime;

    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        Recipe *recipe = nil;

        if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            recipe = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipe = recipe;
    }
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}


@end
```

Comment: So far as I know, Xcode has no special facilities for handling JSON.

Comment: (Did you perhaps mean iOS or OSx?)

Comment: And do you have a question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: iOS. The Question is clear, how to pass the JSON data to the table and remove the Array that currently has.

Comment: Then tag it iOS, not Xcode.

Comment: Maybe if you rephrase and clearly state your question as a "How do I..." or "Why does this throw an error...", etc, we can better answer your question. Also, if you could isolate your code example to a smaller part instead of posting your whole view controller. It would make it much easier.

Comment: Eddwin, it's a little unclear what you're asking.  It could be your best bet is to look at one of the many tutorials on this ... http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/ios-programming-recipe-16-populating-a-uitableview-with-data-from-the-web/ .. **TIP** be sure to only look at **very recent tutorials** since it is, today, incredibly easy to use JSON in iOS. (In the old days you had to use libraries, etc)

Comment: @HotLicks, is there a chance you could delete, consolidate, or perhaps start a short novel with your five cluttercomments there dude?!  :)

Comment: I dont want to use AFNetworking. but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you're asking but these **code fragments** may help:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *rawFromCloud;

#define yourUrl [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blah.com/json/stubs"]

-(void)fromCloud:(void(^)(void))after
    {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{
        self.rawStubsFromCloud = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourUrl];
        after();
        });
    }

NSError* error;
NSDictionary* jdic = [NSJSONSerialization
    JSONObjectWithData:self.rawFromCloud
    options:kNilOptions
    error:&error];

//CRITICAL -- do this, to see what is going on:
NSLog(@"%@", jdic); //to see the fields available

NSArray* stubs = [jdic objectForKey:@"stubs"];
```

that's it - you have an array !

```
for ( NSDictionary *stub in stubs )
    {
    NSString *nn = [stub objectForKey:@"userName"];
    NSLog("one userName %@", nn);
    }
```

(Footnote, you also have the "new" syntax stub[@"userName"] but the 'objectForKey' syntax is easier for beginners, I think. Cheers, hope it helps.)

Comment: Hey @Leo!  It's **somewhat** unclear, it's not totally unclear.  I think it's pretty certain that: Eddwin is just confused about how to take a "name":[] type of field, and populate an NSArray with it.  If so, the above should get it done for him.  **I think English is not Eddwin's first language, we have to be reasonable right?**

Comment: Define reasonable. I define it, for StackOverflow, as answering well crafted questions. Homework questions of this sort, coupled with badly formatted question (regardless of the reason), should not encouraged.

Comment: I'm the most aggressive "Close"r on SO  :) It's a tough call; if you think it should be Close'd, click the Close button.  For me, it's just an easyish question, in a difficult field, but with a number of bad grammar/similar mistakes (like mentioning "Xcode"). Rhetorical questions don't really help and just add clutter. Try not to be (like me) rude :)

Comment: Solved the question on my own and it was pretty simple I just needed to properly locate the dictionary and add a indexpath.row to the tableView. Note: Thanks for the people with good will and also humble people for helping. English is my second language and Im new on xcode so cannot formulate a good Question. Just want to let people that behaved very rude the following. "Before running we must learn how to walk"

Comment: Epa Eddwin! You know, lately on this site there is a "crisis" of crappy questions you know? Funnily enough, sometimes I ask questions, about something obscure. And everyone thinks it's a horrible question and tries to close it :) (You can see many examples of this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896298/c-sharp-extension-function-but-with-generics )  Like Leo says, people come along asking "homework" questions, you know? Moderators try to tidy the site. I think what happen is sometimes someone like you with a good question gets "caught up" in this! Heh! I hope that makes sense. chao!